# What can the Z size/offset in Blender Render's Mapping panel be used for?

Tags: uv, blender-internal-render-engine

After unwrapping an object and assigning a texture in Blender Render, there's a Mapping panel in the Properties panel -> Texture. Part of the Mapping panel has Offset and Size options with z values included. This doesn't seem useful, since UV mapping is based on only x and y values. What can the z-values be used for?


I tried changing the z values with a sort of modified plane. I thought since the plane had some dimension in the z-axis, something would happen, but nothing did.


[image]